# AWS Codepipeline Continue Previous Execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS CodePipeline in order to automatically check out code, build an application with CodeBuild and deploy the application to an ECS cluster for development. After that I inserted a manual step to approve deployment to the staging environment. This works well. However, when I run the pipeline again, there seems to be no way to approve the actions in one of previous executions. As far as I can see, I can only push the latest build artifact to staging (and later to production). This is surely not, what I would like to do. I could use more than one pipeline - one for each stage - for this, but than, what is the manual approval good for?

Comment: you can use it to approve a code change before it can progress further down your pipeline. Manual approvals make it easier for the teams to manage and review code changes before they are deployed, can notify approvers in several ways including email, SMS, etc.

Comment: True, but since a pipeline is typically initiated using a code comiit, the state of the devel line is essentially "resetting" any downstream states of the pipeline. You can not progress an artifact from staging to production if the source code has changed intermittently, and a new version has been rolled out to the development stage.

Answer (score 2):

Currently updating a pipeline will end all in-flight executions at the end of their current action. This includes cancelling in-flight approvals.

After updating your pipeline you can click "Release Change" to have a fresh execution run through your pipeline and after that the changes will continue to be released as usual.

> Unlike creating a pipeline, editing a pipeline does not rerun the most
>   recent revision through the pipeline. If you want to run the most
>   recent revision through a pipeline you've just edited, you must
>   manually rerun it. Otherwise, the edited pipeline will run the next
>   time you make a change to a source location configured in the source
>   stage of the pipeline. For information, see Start a Pipeline Manually
>   in AWS CodePipeline.

From the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-edit.html